# Check four conditions in IF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have four conditions as follows:

```
17.5 < value < 21.5
60 < value < 125
value < 0.03
value > 0.98
```

If all these four conditions are true then the answer must be "Pass" and if any of these four conditions is false then the answer must be "Fail".

How can I achieve this in a single formula?

Comment: I'd like to answer your question but it is not worded well. Can you please be more descriptive about exactly what the four conditions are so I can provide an answer? Thx.

Comment: 17.5<value<21.5 , 60<value<125 , value<0.03 , value>0.98.

Comment: So, just combine those with `AND`? Note that you need to wrap `<` and `>` in code as they get interpreted as HTML otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the four values to be tested are in cells A1:A4, use:

```
  =AND(AND(A1<21.5,A1>17.5),AND(A2>60,A2<125),A3<0.03,A4>0.98)
```